Are there any Linux systems where the home for root is not /root?
I am looking at a script and it contains these two lines:
HOME="$( grep ^root: /etc/passwd | awk -F ':' '{ print $6 }' )" 
export HOME 

This of course loads the variable named HOME with /root.
Setting aside whether over-writing the system variable is intended or accidental (this author wrote all variables as all-caps--which we all know to never do), is this even relevant data on any system?  Are there any systems (Linux distributions) out there where the home directory for root is something other than /root?  Which systems?
(Yes, sure, one could potentially change said directory, but let's keep that aside for now.)
(The variable "${HOME}" is never called but may impact other called scripts.)

/root is defined as optional, but is also the recommend default location for the home directory of the root user. - see here FHS 3.0 - Some systems might use /home/root, especially systems which use LDAP authentification, or some other custom directory.

In the olden days, root's home directory would be just plain /.

How olden would that be?  As in how old a system would I need before worrying?  @BobGoddard

Yeah, I just don't recall ever seeing a system where (out of the box) root's home was in /home (or anywhere except /root).  @paladin

I am talking about before LFS became into being, I'm sure it's over 20 years ago when I last saw root's home set to /. The point being, it does not really matter where it is, just as long as it is set up correctly, probably on the root  file system.

I think the oldest running system I've seen on this network is running SuSe 11 so only about five years past end of life.  There might be something older but I hope not pushing two decades.  I'll keep an eye out though.  Maybe I'll set an alert/e-mail if any such system hits with this script.  I still have to discover if anything in these 5000+ lines of code (or any subsequent script calls) would be impacted by a change to $HOME.

There could be such a system. That's enough. The sole fact it can be changed advocates for the practice of using the information provided by the system and not assuming anything. So, you shouldn't care whether such system exists, you must always ask system about user's home directory, even for root.
With Linux, parsing /etc/passwd manually to extract the user home directory is not the best way to do things, as there is PAM and it may be set up to use various authentication providers, so the valid user might even not exist in /files (I expect root always exists though). Typically the login program (login, sshd, sddm, etc.) sets important environment variables such as HOME for the interactive session; cron also sets HOME for its scripts and used to parse /etc/passwd for that, but nowadays it uses PAM for that, too, consult man 5 crontab; systemd also sets environment for its units. Therefore, in a normal Linux system you should never need to do this yourself.
Besides that, you seem to hate all caps variables, but in this context is the only correct way of doing this. This is not just a variable, this is variable being exported to the environment, and not just some variable, but well known variable. There's a convention dating from ages even before Unix, that environment variable names are in all caps (probably, stemmed from the fact initially character tables didn't have lowercase). Very rarely, you can find some variables from more recent times that ignore this convention (the only example I know of is http_proxy), but HOME is ancient enough so all the software in the world in all systems expects it to be in caps. Other shell variables are, by convention, set to lower case, to not clash with environment. You really stop hating all caps and stick to that convention, too.

You have woefully miscontrued what I have said about all-caps variables.  All system and environment variables should be all-caps.  When writing a script (or on the command line) one should avoid creating all-caps variables due to the potential to accidentally over-write a sys or env variable.  Never do this.  If one intends to over-write (or potentially create) a sys or env variable (and there is no better manner by which to solve that problem) then by all means employ all-caps.
